# How to get multiselect attribute value of a product in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, multiselect-attribute

I have created multiselect custom attribute for product. See https://prnt.sc/sp7wgn
I want to display the selected option value on frontend using phtml file.
How can i do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to check if attribute settings are correct set or not

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YKqI.png]

template code

```
$attribute_string = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

$attribute_array = explode(', ', $attribute_string);
```

Comment: Thanx this worked for me

Comment: Can you tell me how can i get the url for the same . I need attribute value url too along with the name

Comment: any idea???????????