# How to get custom product attribute from productCollection

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-collection, customer-attribute

I use magento 2.4.
I have product collection in catalog view.
There I have loop:

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
.
.
.
                <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
                <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): $i++; ?>
```

Inside of that loop I want to get custom attribute like so:

```
<?php echo $_product->getData('available_soon');?>
```

Now I know that I can't get it because of collection so I write my plugin.
di.xml

```
namespace [Vendor]\Front\Block\Product;


use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;

/**
 * Product list
 * @api
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    /**
     * Retrieve loaded category collection
     *
     * @return AbstractCollection
     */
    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(['available_soon']);

        $categoryId = $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $product->setData('category_id', $categoryId);
        }

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

However, still I don`t have that custom attribute here.
Can some one explain me what I doing ring here ?

Comment: If any one search for it. I found solution like so:
$collection = clone $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
        return $collection->clear()->addAttributeToSelect('available_soon')->load();

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313773/how-to-get-multiselect-attribute-value-of-a-product-in-magento-2/313774#313774

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?php 
    $available_soon = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('available_soon')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    echo $available_soon;
?>
```